# Is this chord progression possible?

Tags: chord-progressions

recently I've been thinking a chord progression that I'm not sure whether it's correct or uncommon. I'm just a music lover and never go into music theory deep. I just play by my ear and the chord sound a bit same to my expected progression. It just very easy chord...

`F C C Em`

The second C chord is inversion that is EGC. This chord progression I just simply hum it and put it together like this, any opinion? I'm not a professional music person...

Comment: After the C/E you change one note to form Em. All very close and tidy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you play the natural chords in the key of C, you get:

C / Dm / Em / F / G / Am / Bdim / C

If you sing the scale doh re mi ... (C D E ...) along with this sequence you will see that it fits.

Your sequence seems to be based on the key of C.

You use chord 4 (F), chord 1 (C), chord 1 (C 1st inversion), chord 3 (Em)

So yes, it is absolutely fine although a little unusual.  The main thing is that it sounds good to you!

Answer (score 1):

In music, "is X possible?", where X is anything, the answer will always be YES. You can do anything in music. All rules are made to be broken.

Your example is simple, all chords belong to C major scale. Nothing's shocking.